# What is the point of 一名 in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, words

(Taken from ジョジョ６部)

> 「女性受刑者が一名頭部を砕かれ変死をとげたというのに…」

I don't really get the point behind 「**一名**」in this sentence.

My guess is that the sentence (badly) translates to something like: "And although one/a female prisoner got her skull broken and died an unnatural death..."

So what does 「**一名**」add to the meaning? Is it used as "count-word", in order to specifically point out that it was **one** prisoner or is there something wrong with my interpretation of the sentence?
Or is it in the end a grammatical necessity?

(To give some context: The sentence (in my opinion) literally states what happened. Due to an incident one prisoner was brutally murdered before above-stated sentence was uttered)

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/36918/9831  -- Compare 「女性受刑者が一名（変死をとげた）」 and 「ペンが三本（あった）」「子豚が一匹（死んだ）」

Comment: After reading the article you linked I think I got the general idea here. I assume that「 一名」 is an adverb that specifies "in how many" the prisoners were affected. Now my reamaining question is if the sentence were「一名の女性受刑者...」would the number (one) be stressed?