# Understanding したら grammar in a sentence

Tags: grammar

1. 30分ほどしたら戻ってきます
   I have a problem understanding the meaning of したら in this sentence.
   Not sure if する can be put directly after 30分ほど(time) in order to describe time spent.
2. 三日したら帰る
   Same problem of understanding したら in this sentence.
   It seems that the sentence translates to "go back after 3 days", but I'm still confused of the grammar of したら.

Thx for the reply~ As far as i know, shouldn't "time spent+もする"
be the correct grammar? Why didn't も appear in the sentence?

Comment: Definition 10 https://jisho.org/word/%E7%82%BA%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This する means "(for time) to pass". You should be able to find this definition in any dictionary.

- しばらくしてからやります。
  I'll do it later (after a while).
- ちょっとしたら彼は来るはずです。
  He should come in no time.
- 5時間はしないと終わらない。
  We can't finish this at least in 5 hours.

Note that this is used **only in a subordinate clause**, usually with a conditional expression (すれば, したら, すると, しないと, etc) or まで/から. In a main clause, 5時間した never means "Five hours passed".

Comment: So the usage of this grammar can be put in "Time+(Particle(can be omitted))+する+Particle"?

Comment: @EricSun A particle may or may not be necessary; the "time" part is actually [just an adverb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/36918/5010).