# Difference between ... 椅子が三つ and 三つの椅子?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, counters

Please, is there a difference between these two sentences!? Duolingo translates them both the same!

1. 部屋に **椅子が三つ** あります。
2. 部屋に **三つの椅子が** あります。

I believe they should have slightly different meanings, but I don't see how or which one is more appropriate in a context or another!

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hello Juliana, welcome to Japanese Stack Exchange! I am marking your question as a duplicate because I think it has already been asked before (see [this entry](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8136/positioning-of-quantities-using-counters)). You can use the search bar at the top of the site to find if your question has been asked before asking it yourself. That said, if you still think there's some aspect of your question that is not discussed in the original answer, you can edit your question to include it.

Comment: [This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/84379/45489) may help too.